# Assigning values to numpy array based on multiple conditions of multiple array

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I have the ocean and atmospheric dataset in netcdf file. Ocean data will contain `nan` or any other value `-999` over land area. For this eample, say it is `nan`. Sample data will look like this:-

```
import numpy as np
ocean = np.array([[2, 4, 5], [6, np.nan, 2], [9, 3, np.nan]])
atmos = np.array([[4, 2, 5], [6, 7, 3], [8, 3, 2]])
```

Now I wanted to apply multiple conditions on ocean and atmos data to make a new array which will have only values from `1` to `8`. For example in ocean data, values between `2` and `4` will be assigned as `1` and values between `4` and `6` will be assigned as `2`. The same comparison goes to atmos dataset as well.

To simplify the comparison and assignment operation, I made a list of bin values and used `np.digitize` to make categories.

```
bin1 = [2, 4, 6]
bin2 = [4, 6, 8]
ocean_cat = np.digitize(ocean, bin1)
atmos_cat = np.digitize(atmos, bin2)
```

which produces the following result:-

```
[[1 2 2]
 [3 3 1]
 [3 1 3]]

[[1 0 1]
 [2 2 0]
 [3 0 0]]
```

Now I wanted element-wise maximum between the above two array results. Therefore, I used `np.fmax` to get the element-wise maximum.

```
final_cat = np.fmax(ocean_cat, atmos_cat)
print(final_cat)
```

which produces the below result:-

```
[[1 2 2]
 [3 3 1]
 [3 1 3]]
```

The above result is almost what I need. The only issue I find here is the missing `nan` value. What I wanted in the final result is:-

```
[[1 2 2]
 [3 nan 1]
 [3 1 nan]]
```

Can someone help me to replace the values with nan from the same index of original ocean array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option would be to mask the output with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
bin1 = [2, 4, 6]
bin2 = [4, 6, 8]
ocean_cat = np.digitize(ocean, bin1)
atmos_cat = np.digitize(atmos, bin2) 
final_cat = np.where(np.isnan(ocean), np.nan,
                     np.fmax(ocean_cat, atmos_cat))
```

If both arrays can have NaNs:

```
final_cat = np.where(np.isnan(ocean)|np.isnan(atmos),
                     np.nan,
                     np.fmax(ocean_cat, atmos_cat))
```

*Or `np.isnan(ocean)&np.isnan(atmos)` if you only want a NaN when both inputs are NaN.*

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3., nan,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1., nan]])
```

Generic approach for any number of input arrays:

```
arrays = [ocean, atmos]
bins = [bin1, bin2]

out = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce([np.isnan(a) for a in arrays]),
               np.nan,
               np.fmax.reduce([np.digitize(a, b) for a,b in zip(arrays, bins)])
               )
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the values are float `-999.0` instead of `nan`.

Comment: @sundar_ima first replace the -999 by NaN ;)

Comment: I accepted your answer. But I have another query. What if the values are masked instead of NaN or -999.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use math operators:

```
out = final_cat * np.nan ** np.isnan(ocean + atmos)
out
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3., nan,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1., nan]])
```